# Overgrown quadriceps of legs - crunching in the knees

Tags: bicycling

I'm training the spinning (cycling) and currently I have overgrown quadriceps of legs (this is the diagnoze of my doctor). He advise me that I should train different part of the legs -not the quadricpes but the two-headed muscles of legs. Do you know any good training only for this part? I don't want to give up with the spinning but also it would be good to keep the health. Any ideas?

Comment: Did he name the "two headed muscles"?

Comment: By "overgrown quad" you mean your legs are quad-dominant? Like your quads are way more developed than your hamstrings?

Answer (score 1):

Nordic curls are the best exercise to fight over-developed quadriceps, why? because it trains the hamstrings, calves, glutes and a little bit of adductors(isometric extension).

Here's how you do you it
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-RBAstMjbNU
[image]